# How to automate creating box (rectangular) polygons in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geometry

Can anyone suggest a way to automate creating rectangle shaped polygons in ArcMap?

If I had many 30m x 60m rectangles to digitize and I just want to click a starting corner coordinate on screen, then a second click for orientation.

Is this more suited towards Python, or ArcObjects, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using the **[Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000)** tool wrapped in a **Python script tool** that uses **[Feature Sets](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001n000000)** to request the two coordinates.

If you are using **ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 or later** then I would recommend doing this as a **[Python Add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p0000001q000000)** instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.   I am using 10.1 and was hoping ArcObjects wouldn't be needed.  A python add-in is similar to a VBA script from years back?  Frank